# Trouble compiling using Cygwin

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, cygwin

I need to use cygwin/x to run a file, I am very new to cygwin and linux. I am having trouble compiling said file. I had someone tell me it sounds like my bin directory is not in the path. I do not know if that is true or not. If it is could someone help me fix that.

```
$ gcc qlens
```

returns

```
qlens: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Current version of gcc

```
$ gcc -v
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)
```

Type of file

```
$ file qlens
qlens: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable
```

Can someone help me compile this file and get it running?

Answer (score 1):

The lack of file extension is confusing GCC.
Before compiling, rename it

```
  mv qlens qlens.c
  gcc -o qlens qlens.c
```

To test

```
./qlens
```

Comment: Using the command "mv qlens qlens.c"
  "gcc -o qlens qlens.c" yielded a large amount of error lines and warning messages. When I tested ./qlens returned "bash: ./qlens: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Comment: if "gcc -o qlens qlens.c" produce error message than your program has errors that does not allow gcc to complete the compilation. Look on them and try to solve it

Comment: qlens: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable  ????   I am really confused, the gcc is a compiler so it needs/expects a text file containing C language. From where this qlens is coming from ?